# Attempting to download metadata from 'net.pipe://localhost/abc.svc' using WS-Metadata Exchange. This URL does not support DISCO

Tags: c#, wcf, svcutil.exe, net.pipe

Got this error while generating proxy by svcutil:

```
"Attempting to download metadata from 'net.pipe://localhost/abc.svc' using WS-Metadata Exchange. This URL does not support DISCO."
```

The service is compiled without error & working fine with `http` earlier.
The wsdl generated is working fine for `net.pipe` too without problem even after the error while generating proxy with svcutil.

To make sure its generating new files are generated, I deleted all old files & then generate files using svcutil, then use them. It gives same error and also generates files which when used gives no problem while consuming services.

I am just puzzled why this error is there when every thing is working fine.

Comment: Do you have a mex endpoint for the service? `<endpoint address="mexnetpipe" binding="mexNamedPipeBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />`

Comment: @Tim, My mex endpoint is like   <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexNamedPipeBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>

Answer (score 1):

Pranav,

your mex endpoint is right. When you are using netNamedPipeBinding or netTcpBinding you need to make some settings in services and IIS.

Refer [Hosting WCF service with netTcpBinding or netNamedPipeBinding in IIS](http://dotnetmentors.com/hosting-wcf-service-with-nettcpbinding-or-netnamedpipebinding-in-iis.aspx)

Comment: that was really useful article +1 for this. I tried but error doesn't stop. What bugs me most is, although there is error in generating proxy but files are generated and when used works successfully as intended. I wish I know why error is occuring.

Answer (score 1):

That is not ERROR message. I would say just INFO, not even WARNING...

I guess you have something like the following config and try to run svcutil on net.pipe.

```
    <service name="Service" ...>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.pipe://localhost/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="Service"
                  binding="netNamedPipeBinding"
                  contract="IService" />
        <endpoint address="Service/mex"
                  binding="mexNamedPipeBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
   </service>
   ...
   <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="False" />
```

svcutil will give message like "This URL does not support DISCO" and still successfully generate files

Now you can change serviceMetadata  to

```
    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpGetUrl="http://localhost:8182/Service/mex" />
```

and run for example

```
    svcutil.exe /t:code /l:cpp /ser:Auto http://localhost:8182/Service/mex
```

It will generate the same client proxy code as running on net.pipe but now with following output...

```
    Attempting to download metadata from 'http://localhost:8182/Service/mex' using WS-Metadata Exchange or DISCO.
```